# Riverpod error: Undefined class 'ScopedReader'

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Now I use [hooks_riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/) package to manage states.
Then I wanted to use FutureProvider to fetch data from firestore.
I read this official document([API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/FutureProvider-class.html)).
The example on the link said that UI will be like:

```
Widget build(BuildContext, ScopedReader watch) {
  AsyncValue<Configuration> config = watch(configProvider);

  return config.when(
    loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
    data: (config) {
      return Text(config.host);
    },
  );
}
```

I did as it said but I got an error "Undefined class 'ScopedReader'".

my code is below.

**Provider definition**

```
final quizListProvider = FutureProvider<List>((ref) async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final quizPack = ref.watch(quizPackProvider).state;
  List<Map> quizList = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < quizPack.length; i++) {
    final content = await firestore.collection('quizes').doc(quizPack[i]).get();
    quizList.add(content.data()!);
  }
  return quizList;
});
```

**UI**

```
class Quiz extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext, ScopedReader watch) {
    AsyncValue<List> quizList = watch(quizListProvider);

    return quizList.when(
      data: (quizList) {
        return Scaffold(
         some widgets are here
        );
      },
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
    );
  }
}
```

I wonder why it happened.
Can you help me plz?

Answer (score 13):

Creator of Riverpod changed ScopedReader to WidgetRef, now that's how you should use it:

```
class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    int count = ref.watch(counterProvider);
    ...
  }
}
```

According to changelog - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod/versions/1.0.0-dev.11/changelog#100-dev0